# Updating Elastic Beanstalk stack and NodeJS at the same time

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The Problem:
Elastic Beanstalk versions only support specific versions of NodeJS.

EG:

2.0.7 supports Node 0.12.9

2.1.3 supports Node 0.12.15

There are no longer nice 'bridging' versions so you can update the Environment and wait for it to become stable before updating the NodeJS version.

Is there any way to update both at once?

I tried doing it via the CLI with:

`aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name environment-name --solution-stack-name "64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.3 running Node.js" --option-settings "OptionName=NodeVersion, Namespace=aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs, Value=0.12.15"`

That only updated the NodeJS version to an invalid value, putting the Environment out of order with seemingly no way to recover it.

Alternatively, is there some other way to do this?

Comment: EBS = Elastic Block Store.

Comment: Sorry - little loose with the acronyms, frustration makes for bad shorthand.

ELB it is.

Comment: Cloning the environment isn't ideal, but might be the only option.

1 - Set the invalid NodeJS version.

2 - Wait for ENV to go Grey

3 - Clone

4 - Fix up the security groups and WHY

5 - Swap the URLs.

Comment: ELB = Elastic Load Balancer... Just type the whole thing out if you don't know the correct acronyms.

Comment: For Stack Overflow typing it out in full is likely better even if you know the correct initialism/acronym.

Comment: @Pyro Did you ever come up with a solution worth sharing?  I'm in the same pickle (different versions).

Comment: @EdStaub my memory is hazy :(

Can't recall if it ever recovered from the invalid state or if I just ended up re-creating the environment.

With the newer version Amazon seems to ensure there's an upgrade path available, and I believe it is now possible to update both the environment and nodejs version with a single command.

I have run into a few scenarios where the environment stays 'unhealthy' for frustratingly long times, but for the most part Elastic Beanstalk has been behaving pretty well since this incident.